# Firestore: Efficient way to update data from cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to work out what might be the most efficient and scalable solution to updating data from user interaction within a table view cell. Within a cell, a user can `like` a post, `share` a post or `view` video. The video could be watched multiple times so the counter would need updating for number of times watched.

In all cases, i plan to run Cloud Functions to update data wherever the data is duplicated, so i am focusing on updating one post.

---

Three options i am considering:

#### 1. Update firebase on every interaction.

Basically if the user taps like, share or watches the video, it would update the post in firebase. If they unlike or unshare straight after, it would remove from firebase.

This seems like the simplest solution, and would be immediate which is what i am after, but potentially if the user likes/unlikes, shares/unshares and watches a video 3 times, that's 7 writes for a single post for a single user. Additionally, the cloud function would pick up these 7 actions and perform the writes in other areas of the database.

#### 2. As above, but update views in batch transaction

Following the same process as above for likes/shares, but only updating the views counter once the table view cell has disappeared. Once it has, will run a transaction to update the views in the post in a single write. Therefore, worst case scenario would be 5 writes per post + cloud function firing 5 times.

I think this is my preferred solution and most logical, although the batch transaction will need to be called if the user scrolls and cell disappears, if the app terminates and if the app goes into the background, which i imagine isn't too problematic.

#### 3. Store all data, and update post when table view cell disappears

Instead of writing likes/shares as they happen, store what the user is doing, then once the table view cell disappears, call the transaction to update the like, share and views in a single transaction.

For scalability, this seems the most logical? But there would be a delay on the like notification reaching the user. (Again, i think this isn't a problem).

---

My preferred option is Option 2, i am just curious about how effective that would be if the app grew, and 5 writes becomes 500 writes, but then 500 writes may be acceptable?

If anyone has any advice, or potentially another option, i would be grateful.

Comment: I would probably defer updates using a `Timer`.  Create a dictionary of `[Object:Int]` where `Object` is your firebase data model object.  When an object is modified you set the count `Int` in the dictionary to, say, 2.  Have a timer that ticks every second.  When the timer ticks, decrement the count in the dictionary for each object.  When the count reaches 0, update the server and remove the object from the dictionary.  This way the server will be updated 2 seconds after the user stops interacting with it.

Comment: You will probably want to immediately write any pending changes when your app moves to the background.